# a simple way to editing elements in a 2D array Python:

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science, data-analysis

I would like to be able to perform operations on specific elements in a 2D array, if it meets a criterion. in the below example the code makes any value < 0.5 = 0.

Does anyone know of a simple way of doing this? Below is my code, but im sure there is a simpler way.

```
import numpy as np

x = 5
y = 5

x3 = np.random.rand(x,y)

def choice(arr):
    row = -1
    column = -1
    for i in arr:
        row += 1
        for j in i:
            column += 1
            if j >= 0.5:
                arr[row,column] = j
            else:
                arr[row,column] = 0
                
            if column == y - 1:
                column = -1
    
    return arr

y3 = choice(x3.copy())
```

Comment: First of all, you can really simplify your code with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Go to page 2 of the NumPy tutorial you're reading?

Comment: Hi, please go through the NumPy tutorial again as mentioned above. If I understand correctly the solution is a one-liner `x3[x3 < 0.5] = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To zero all the indices that are < 0.5,

```
>>> x3 = np.random.rand(5, 5)
>>> x3
array([[0.50866152, 0.56821455, 0.88531855, 0.36596337, 0.08705278],
       [0.96215686, 0.19553668, 0.15948972, 0.20486815, 0.74759719],
       [0.36269356, 0.54718917, 0.66196524, 0.82380099, 0.77739482],
       [0.0431448 , 0.47664036, 0.80188153, 0.8099637 , 0.65258638],
       [0.84862179, 0.22976325, 0.03508076, 0.72360136, 0.76835819]])
>>> x3[x3 < .5] = 0
>>> x3
array([[0.50866152, 0.56821455, 0.88531855, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.96215686, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.74759719],
       [0.        , 0.54718917, 0.66196524, 0.82380099, 0.77739482],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.80188153, 0.8099637 , 0.65258638],
       [0.84862179, 0.        , 0.        , 0.72360136, 0.76835819]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for enumerate and ternary condition introduction you can do :

```py
import numpy as np

x = 5
y = 5

x3 = np.random.rand(x,y)

def choice(arr):
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(arr):
        for col_idx, val in enumerate(row) :
            arr[row_idx,col_idx] = val if val >= 0.5 else 0
    return arr

y3 = choice(x3.copy())
```

But AKX solution is just better.